# Target IE's text size with media queries or js

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, media-queries

**Is there a way to target changes selected by the user in IE's View > Text Size using media queries or similar?**

So, for example, when the user changes the text size to "large" I can call something like `@media (text-size: large)` and apply specific styles. Could also do with any js solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to build an in-memory element with font-size:medium and compare its width to a control element with a known font size.

You can use this information to add a class (small, large, etc.) to  which you can use in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way knowing what the user set textsize is.